# Python List and If Statement issue

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a list called listExitPrice already created with values in it. I was hoping to separate out this list into multiple other lists as you can see below. I wanted to separate it by looking into the what listExitPrice[k] and checking it it is greater than 0, if it is I wanted to follow the path for else. Vise versa. This code yields "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuples" for the first row of the else statement. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
countSell = 0
countHold = 0
for k in listExitPrice:
    if k == 0:
        listBuyDateAP[countHold] = listBuyDate[k]
        listStockNameAP[countHold] = listStockName[k]
        listEntryPriceAP[countHold] = listEntryPrice[k]
        listVolumeAP[countHold] = listVolume[k]
        countHold = countHold + 1
    else:
        listBuyDatePT[countSell] = listBuyDate[k]
        listStockNamePT[countSell] = listStockName[k]
        listEntryPricePT[countSell] = listExitPrice[k]
        listVolumePT[countSell] = listVolume[k]
        listExitPricePT[countSell] = listEntryPrice[k]
        listSellDatePT[countSell] = listSellDate[k]
        countSell = countSell + 1
```

Comment: That's because k is probably a tuple. Try printing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what your K values look like, I can only guess based on the error that it is not an integer (which can be used to index arrays) but a tuple instead. You probably want to print out listExitPrice to see for yourself.

Comment: How would i get the loop to run where k would be an int. In c++ I see this as for(int = k , k< 10, k++), this would cycle through a string with k being a int for the index. is there a way to replicate this in python?

Comment: Once again that depends on what your listExitPrice looks like. Assuming it looks like a list of tuples with a single element ie ` [(1,) , (2,) ,(3,)] ` then you should replace your for statement with : ` for k[0] in listExitPrice : ` 

Again I cannot say for sure without knowing what listExitPrice looks like. Perhaps you might want to simply ` print(listExitPrice) ` to see what it looks like. 

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! thank you! I printed it out and it wasn't an int!